# Dynamic DIV Container Height

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, html, height

i know every web-developer hates this topic, but anyway... i found no **good solution** for this.

i have 3 DIVs, **two static** (grey ones) and **one dynamic** (red one).
The image describes the whole window. Such as at a chat application.

[image: the div container]

And, yep, the question is: how do i get the red one dynamic when the window get resized (or on other layout changes).
Is there a soltuon **without javascript**, just CSS(3)?

**Edit**: Condition: the DIV on bottom should stay on bottom of the window, sorry.

Additional Information

I already done it in JS (jQuery), but i think this is no good practice at all. (The resize method for the middle DIV have to implement in every "layout changing event").

Example here:

```
var div1 = $('#div1').outerHeight(true);
var div2 = $('#div2').outerHeight(true);
var div3Padding = $('#div3').outerHeight(true) - $('#div3').innerHeight();

$('#div3').css({ height: window.innerHeight - (div1 + div2) - div3Padding });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With absolute positioning, you can do:  http://jsfiddle.net/rQVmK/

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    #div1, div2, div3 { position: absolute; }
    #div1 {
        border: 3px solid #eee;
        height: 30px;
        top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    }
    #div2 {
        border: 3px solid #e00;
        top: 30px; bottom: 30px;
        left: 0; right: 0;
    }
    #div3 {
        border: 3px solid #eee;
        height: 30px;
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="div1">Top</div>
    <div id="div2">Middle</div>
    <div id="div3">Bottom</div>
</html>
```

Comment: thats a good solution. just the borders have to implement into the tops and bottoms. made my day, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning and specifying both a top and bottom position.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i'm missing something but that is how divs, and all block-level elements, react naturally, all you have to do is properly contain them and not hand them a fixed height since they have `height:auto` by default. Try this setup for example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        This is a header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is a content div
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        This is a footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:378px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #515151;
}

.header, .footer {
    height:60px;
}

.header {
    background-color:#00B4FF;
}

.footer {
    background-color:#515151;
}

.content {
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KRwvf/)

Comment: "Condition: the DIV on bottom should stay on bottom of the window"

Answer (score 0):

You can use css grid for this:

```css
.parent {
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

reference: [Pancake Stack](https://1linelayouts.glitch.me/)